# What is the purpose of CLS files and DLL files in VB?

Tags: vb6

Does anyone have a good explanation of what the different meaning of the CLS, DLL, and VBP files in a VB project are?

Comment: It's informative to open the .vbp/.frm/.bas etc files with notepad.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- CLS file is a class file containing the source code for one class.
- VBP file is a project file. You open a VBP in the VB6 IDE to browse or edit the code for that project.
- Projects can also be included in groups (VBG files), roughly equivalent to what .Net calls *solutions*.
- DLL file is a compiled executable library built from your VB6 source code. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_link_library)

The VB6 manual [explains many of the file extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241721(v=VS.60).aspx), including CLS and VBP.

Answer (score 6):

In pre .Net days .cls files were where your class modules lived.  Dll's stand for Dynamic Link Libraries and is a compiled assembly.  VBP stands for Visual Basic Project and is the master file for the whole project.

Answer (score 4):

```
cls - class file
dll -  Dynamic Link Libraries/Assembly
vbp - Visual Basic Project
```

Have a look at [Visual Basic File Types](http://www.hitmill.com/programming/vb/filetypes.html)