# What is the file name extension for visual basic?

Tags: vb6

Is it .vb like the latest version, I'm talking about version 6.0 (classic)? I'm trying to properly title a visual basic script for a module I need. If I have to redo a script because I cannot name a extension I am going to be mad.

Comment: If you are talking about "scripts" - that is not the same as a vb6 applications. There is a VBScript, the extension for that files would be VBS. But that has nothing to do with vb6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several:

- .cls (class file)
- .frm (form)
- .frx (form - binary information)
- .ctl (custom control)
- .ctx (custom control binary information)
- .vbp (project)
- .vbg (project group)
- .bas (module)
- Probably more...

The one you want is most likely .cls.

This answer as also good definitions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4385921/755977

Comment: Good list - I've added some more

Comment: You can just save a vb file and see the extension and you can definitely google it but why ask it here? It's so simple and you can easily figure it out yourself! I vb extensions-(googledhttps://www.google.com/search?q=visual+basic+extensions&oq=visual+basic+extensions&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.584j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and i found list of extensions you are lucky PhilDulac gave you a list usually these questions do not get answered!

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa241721(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#project-file-extensions):

> ## Project File Extensions
>
> Visual Basic produces a number of files when you create and compile a project. These can be categorized as
>   follows: design-time, miscellaneous development, and run-time.
>
> Design time files are the building blocks of your project: basic
>   modules (.bas) and form modules (.frm), for example.
>
> Miscellaneous files are produced by various processes and functions of
>   the Visual Basic development environment: Package and Deployment
>   Wizard dependency files (.dep), for example.
>
> ### Design-time and Miscellaneous Files
>
> The following table lists all the design-time and miscellaneous other files that may be produced
>   when you develop an application:
>
> **TABLE 1** (Extension,   Description)
>
> - .bas   Basic module
> - .cls   Class module
> - .ctl   User Control file
> - .ctx   User Control binary file
> - .dca   Active Designer cache
> - .ddf   Package and Deployment Wizard CAB information file
> - .dep   Package and Deployment Wizard dependency file
> - .dob   ActiveX document form file
> - .dox   ActiveX document binary form file
> - .dsr   Active Designer file
> - .dsx   Active Designer binary file
> - .dws   Deployment wizard script file
> - .frm   Form file
> - .frx   Binary form file
> - .log   Log file for load errors
> - .oca   Control TypeLib cache file
> - .pag   Property page file
> - .pgx   Binary property page file
> - .res   Resource file
> - .tlb   Remote Automation TypeLib file
> - .vbg   Visual Basic group project file
> - .vbl   Control licensing file
> - .vbp   Visual Basic project file
> - .vbr   Remote Automation registration file
> - .vbw   Visual Basic project workspace file
> - .vbz   Wizard launch file
> - .wct   WebClass HTML template
>
> ### Run-Time Files
>
> When you compile your application, all the necessary design-time files are included in the run-time executable files.
>   Run-time files are listed in the following table:
>
> **TABLE 2** (Extension,   Description)
>
> - .dll   In-process ActiveX component
> - .exe   Executable file or ActiveX component
> - .ocx   ActiveX control
> - .vbd   ActiveX document state file
> - .wct   WebClass HTML template

---

In addition I have seen `.vbi` used as an "include" file. Basically a `.bas` module. I'm not sure how common this practice is.